# how can we redirect one url to other url for certain period of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want some javascript/jquery code to redirect my website to another domain but only within a certain period of time like redirect between 2 a.m. - 4:00 a.m. so it will be working only for two hour in the rest of the time website will work normally without redirect.

Comment: Can you show what you have at the moment? Where are you expecting this functionality to be inserted?

Comment: just create a js file with a function which checks current time, and redirects to specified url if  time is between 2AM and 4 AM. include that js file in the master page(s). and call that function in $(document).ready of Master page(s)

Answer (score 0):

You must do something like this:

```js
// Declare your interval, which will call the redirectFunction every seconds
var redirectInterval = setInterval(redirectFunction, 1000);

// Interval will call your function in 1 sec.
// So we call it directly here
redirectFunction();

function redirectFunction() {
    var hours = new Date().getHours();
    if (hours >= 2 && hours <= 4) {
       // Replace by your URL
       document.location.href = "https://google.com";
    }
}

// Call this to cancel the redirection
// clearInterval(redirectInterval);
```

But the best solution would be to redirect your user to the server side.

Comment: This solution is problematic by two points:
1) You assume the time zone if the user is the same as server time zone
2) If the user change manually the time, it's not gonna work.

Use a server side solution, not client side: detect what is the time on you server, and manualy redirect the user

Comment: Sure, you're right! I add extra comment in my answer. I did this js snippet related to the request of the question owner.

Comment: if you want to redirect based on user's time, handling from server won't work in case website is deployed somewhere else.

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider So the best practice will be to do this server side.

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider You're right, but we need some extra explanation about the exact request about that.... server's time or user's time